# Copy constructor not called !

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I don't understand why in this case copy constructor isn't called. Can some one please explain ?

```
#include <iostream>

class foo
{
    int* ptr;
    public:
    foo()
    {
        std::cout << "\n Constructor \n" ;
        ptr  = new int;
        *ptr = 10;
    }

    foo( const foo* &obj )  // Copy Constructor
    {
         std::cout << "\n Copy Constructor \n" ;
         ptr  = new int;
         *(this->ptr) = *(obj->ptr);
    }

    // Copy Assignment Operator

    ~foo()  // Destructor
    {
        delete ptr;
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo* objOne = new foo;
    foo* objTwo = objOne ;

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because you're just creating another *pointer* to the *same* object, not a new object:

```
foo* objOne = new foo;
foo* objTwo = objOne;
   ^
   |
   +-- these are pointers.
```

If you want a new object, use something like:

```
foo objTwo = objOne;
```

and fix your copy constructor:

```
foo (const foo &obj) ...
```

The following snippet shows one way to do it:

```
#include <iostream>

class foo {
    public:

    foo () {
        std::cout << "constructor" << std::endl;
        ptr  = new int;
        *ptr = 10;
    }

    foo (const foo &obj) {
        std::cout << "copy constructor" << std::endl;
        ptr  = new int;
        *(this->ptr) = *(obj.ptr);
    }

    ~foo () {
        delete ptr;
    }

    private:

    int* ptr;
};

int main()
{
    foo objOne;
    foo objTwo = objOne ;
    return 0;
}
```

And this outputs:

```
constructor
copy constructor
```

as you would expect.

Answer (score 3):

```
 foo( const foo* &obj )
```

is not the copy constructor

```
 foo( const foo &obj )
```

is

Also, you are copying object pointers, not objects. You can't define a copy constructor for object pointers. The usual solution in C++ is to create a smart pointer class which wraps the pointer. See:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer

Answer (score 2):

You're copying a POINTER to an object, not the object.  Hence no copy constructor call - you're just assigning objTwo to be the same address as objOne.

Answer (score 0):

Just a idea, try calling it like this:

```
foo* objTwo(objOne);
```

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself? ;)

Answer (score 0):

The copy constructor takes a *reference* to a const object as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong signature for a copy constructor...

It can't be a pointer....

```
foo( const foo &obj )
```